# Coding picture box from runtime and adding an event to it

Tags: c#, controls, runtime, picturebox

In C# Forms I can easily add PictureBox in Design Mode and then double click on MouseHover and MouseLeave events and make the background color change to red and blue etc. I see that in "Form1Designer.cs" tab the below code gets populated:

```
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(203, 56);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(417, 273);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseLeave);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseHover);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1Hover";
        this.Text = "Form1Hover";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

However, I am supposed to do this in runtime so when someone looks at the design form it is not supposed to show any picture box in it. If I open a new form and copy and paste the above code in "Form1Designer.cs" tab then all the code is highlighted with red errors. So I couldn't make it work here.

I was able to succeed runtime picture box coding by doing the below code.
In "Form1Designer.cs" tab I only added:

```
    this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
```

In "Form1.cs" tab I added:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox(); // got instance of Picture Box here
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseHover);
        pictureBox1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseLeave);
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I have two questions,

Question 1: I guess its not possible to write all the code to generate Picture Boxes and their events in Form1Designer.cs", is that correct?

Question 2: My solution requires me to get instance of Picture Box in "Form1.cs" in the most outer scopes {}; in other words as global as possible. I feel this is not a very clean way to get the instance of the Picture Box my Form1 will be cluttered. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you missed lines in designer generated code where the ````pictureBox1```` variable was defined? E.g. ````private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picureBox1;````? Maybe thatswhy all lines become red :)

Comment: Form1.Designer is a generated file, if your change something in the designer view you will lose all your custom code in there. Also, the Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.cs are partial classes. It doesnt 'get more global' if the picturebox is declared in Form1.cs as opposed to Form1.Designer.cs since its the same class in different files.

Answer (score 0):

The Designer generates code for you. So its is perfectly possible for you to write it on your own. If you have Errors pay attention to the messages and if you don't understand them ask google, this usually helps you further.

Adressing your second question: Fixation already gave you a good response. If you look at your class declaration you can see that it is a partial class. the designer generated code declares the same partial class. these two (or more, if you choose to) parts will be sewn together at runtime. So the private declared members will be in scope throughout all parts of the partial class. Otherwise the designer generated code wouldn't be in scope either.

If you fear that the class will become too cluttered just look for pieces of code that can be extracted into its own classes. You are using an object oriented Language and thus have the power to organize yourself

If you want to see no picturebox on startup but it should be shown later you could change the visible property to false.

If you really want to manually code in the picturebox I recommend that you closely study the designer generated code and experiment some more.